# phpMyAdmin - Open Link in New Tab

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I just upgraded to pma 4.3.5 and everything seems to be working just fine however when I try to open a link in a new tab (to have multiple tables open in different tabs) I get all sorts of errors and my apache (2.4.9) server starts getting bogged down, until I close the tab.

PHP 5.5.3
MySql 5.6

The strange thing is that the page loads, but is unresponsive. And my main pma tab (the tab I logged in under) still works perfect.

Here's the errors I'm getting:

[image]

the error count in the bottom left just keeps increasing rapidly.

This error is browser independent. Sessions are working normally for other sites. All services have been restarted yet problem persists...

Comment: Have you restarted all services after the installs?

Comment: yes, forgot to mention all services have been restarted problem persists.

Comment: Have you checked whether to update your PHP aswell? Seems like it's all errors retrieved from ajax calls from the PMA_Message class. Could be deprecated functions or newly introduced functions that are not compatible with your current PHP version.

Comment: From PMA site _"phpMyAdmin 4.3.5 Current version compatible with PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.5. Currently recommended version."_

Comment: I assumed those were minimum requirements, I'm using php 5.5 and mysql 5.6

Comment: These are the minimum requirements `PHP 5.2 and MySQL 5`. Frantically I'm quite stuck on this problem. I'll try to dig a bit deeper until then I don't think I can help you

Comment: There's not much info on these errors, and it's so strange because I can have multiple tabs open but it only works by accessing the index.php of pma on each tab, not by right clicking any links or copying any other urls...